# child dynamic link is not triggering

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {

            Button bt = new Button();
            bt.Text = ""+i;
            bt.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(bt);

        }    
    }

    public void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Button selected = sender as Button;
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "i am lable";
        Panel2.Controls.Add(lbl);
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        {                
            Button pb = new Button();    
            pb.Text = selected.Text;    
            pb.Click += new EventHandler(pb_Click);                               
            Panel2.Controls.Add(pb);               
        }
    }

    public void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // how to trigger it 
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }         
}
```

this pb_Click is not trigerring; so guys any idea

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `pb_Click` won't execute. You are adding controls (buttons) into `bt_Click` handler will be removed on next submit. You must have to use `Page_Load` event to add controls dynamically.

You may write/design your code like this: (a trick)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {

            Button bt = new Button();
            bt.Text = "" + i;
            bt.ID = "btn" + i; // Assign unique ID
            bt.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(bt);
        }
        AddButtons();
    }

    public void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["btnId"] = (sender as Button).ID ;
        AddButtons();
    }

    public void AddButtons()
    {
        if (ViewState["btnId"] == null)
            return;
        Button selected = Panel1.FindControl(ViewState["btnId"].ToString()) as Button;

        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "i am lable";
        Panel2.Controls.Add(lbl);
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
        {

            Button pb = new Button();

            pb.Text = selected.Text;

            pb.Click += new EventHandler(pb_Click);
            Panel2.Controls.Add(pb);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tanks man this is really helpful i was trying to add this in difrent function as you but i was not able to track event. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I am facing one more issue in i have also created ine text box in addbutton. and i have set its property to visible= false; now i am trying to modify it to visible = true; so how to acccess this text box value there .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the button in the page_init method and do not add them in the button click or page_load methods.